# If $E(U|X)=0$, then $E(U)=0$?

Tags: statistics

> If $U$ and $X$ are random variables such that $E(U|X)=0$, then $E(U)=0$.

Really? how to prove?

Comment: @evaristegd: Not so, it's true without any assumptions.

Answer (score 5):

$E(U\mid X)$ is actually a random variable which is a certain function of $X$ (say, $g(X)$ for instance). There's a property that says that if you take its expectation you get
$$E\big(E(U\mid X)\big)=E(U).$$

So,
$$E(U)=E\big(E(U\mid X)\big)=E(0)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, given  E(U|X)=0, how to prove U and X are uncorrelated?

Comment: I know now. Because cOV=E(UX)=E(X)*E(U|X)=0

Comment: That's good! One detail, in general $$\text{cov}(U,X)=E\Big(\big(U-E(U)\big)\big(X-E(X)\big)\Big)=E(UX)-E(U)E(X).$$ But in this case $$\text{cov}(U,X)=E(UX)$$is valid because you've already proven that $E(U)=0$.